# How to filter out the fields available for a record type

Tags: apex, soql, record-type, fields

Is there a way to list out the fields available for a specific record type? Maybe an apex or soql solution?

Basically this would mean a list of fields that are available in the record type page layout.

Comment: Do you mean the fields that are on the _page layout_ for a record type as assigned to the current user? (Please [edit] to clarify).

Comment: What's the purpose behind this? There's a number of possible solutions, but the best solution will be the one tailored for your specific situation.